# CSS line up DIV TABLE to stack when longer than width

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Hey all I am trying to find the correct code in order for the input thats within the DIV TABLE to go to the next line if it's too long to display on one line:

The JSFIDDLE is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/stealthrt/1ea8bogm/)

The HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-5 col-xs-offset-2 text-right" style="width: 100%;">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" align="left">
          <h4>Accident Information:</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="Table">
            <div class="Row">
              <div class="Cell" align="right">
                Date of Accident:
              </div>
              <div class="Cell" align="left">
                {AI_DATEOF}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Row">
              <div class="Cell" align="right">
                Type of Accident:
              </div>
              <div class="Cell" align="left">
                {AI_ACCIDENT}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Row">
              <div class="Cell" align="right">
                Accident Location:
              </div>
              <div class="Cell" align="left">
                {AI_LOCATION}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Row">
              <div class="Cell" align="right">
                Accident Details:
              </div>
              <div class="Cell" align="left">
                {AI_DETAILS}
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="Row">
              <div class="Cell" align="right">
                List Of Other Family Members
                <br/> That Were Involved:
              </div>
              <div class="Row" style="width:100%;display:table;">
                <!--Details 1 -->
                <div class="Cell" align="left" style="width:50%; display: table-cell;">
                  <br/>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      Name:
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_NAME}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      ID#
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_ID}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      Relation:
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_RELATION}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!--Details 1 -->
                <div class="Cell" align="left">
                  <br/>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      Name:
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_NAME}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      ID#
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_ID}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      Relation:
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_RELATION}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!--Details 1 -->
                <div class="Cell" align="left">
                  <br/>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      Name:
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_NAME}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      ID#
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_ID}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      Relation:
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_RELATION}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!--Details 1 -->
                <div class="Cell" align="left">
                  <br/>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      Name:
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_NAME}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      ID#
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_ID}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      Relation:
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_RELATION}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!--Details 1 -->
                <div class="Cell" align="left">
                  <br/>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      Name:
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_NAME}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      ID#
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_ID}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      Relation:
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_RELATION}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!--Details 1 -->
                <div class="Cell" align="left">
                  <br/>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      Name:
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_NAME}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      ID#
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_ID}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      Relation:
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_RELATION}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!--Details 1 -->
                <div class="Cell" align="left">
                  <br/>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      Name:
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_NAME}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      ID#
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_ID}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      Relation:
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_RELATION}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!--Details 1 -->
                <div class="Cell" align="left">
                  <br/>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      Name:
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_NAME}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      ID#
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_ID}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      Relation:
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_RELATION}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!--Details 1 -->
                <div class="Cell" align="left">
                  <br/>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      Name:
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_NAME}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      ID#
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_ID}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      Relation:
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_RELATION}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!--Details 1 -->
                <div class="Cell" align="left">
                  <br/>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      Name:
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_NAME}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      ID#
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_ID}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      Relation:
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_RELATION}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

                <!--Details 1 -->
                <div class="Cell" align="left">
                  <br/>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      Name:
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_NAME}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      ID#
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_ID}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="Row">
                    <div class="Cell" align="right">
                      Relation:
                    </div>
                    <div class="Cell" align="left">
                      {AID_RELATION}
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: That most likely would be based on javascript.  You would need to measure the elements with respect to the parent to determine if you stack or not.  Then you just would add or remove a class so that they stack.

Comment: what `input`? are you asking how to wrap the `cell` elements? in your example can you point out the element(s) causing issues?

Comment: @Quoid: Each **<div class="Row">** that has **<!--Details 1 -->** is where i need it to "wrap" as you call it if it goes outside the first **DIV table**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making your own CSS, if you're using Bootstrap, why don't you change the class of `cell` to `col-sm-2` or so on?